# Android GET inside a POST not working

Tags: java, android, post, get

I need to send some variables to be stored into a database, and some to be displayed in the screen in a `PHP` page. I did not find how to do it all together and go to the webpage to show the variables on the screen with the `POST` method so I am trying to do it by passing them through the `URL` with the `GET` method.

`POST` method is working fine, and the variables are stored in the database, but after this, the app does not go to the webpage and shows another variable on the screen. Here is my code:

```
public class Main3Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

public String precio;
URL url;
Button b1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main3);

    b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_pago);
    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()   {
        public void onClick(View v)  {
            try {
                new SendPostRequest().execute();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });



}

public void getMethod() throws IOException {

    url = new URL("https://www.webpage.com/login_app.php?username=" + precio );
}


public class SendPostRequest extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    protected void onPreExecute(){}

    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {

        try {

            URL url = new URL("https://www.webpage.com/login_app.php"); // here is your URL path

            JSONObject postDataParams = new JSONObject();
            postDataParams.put("precio", "1€");
            Log.e("params",postDataParams.toString());

            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);

            OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
            writer.write(getPostDataString(postDataParams));

            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            os.close();

            int responseCode=conn.getResponseCode();

            if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                BufferedReader in=new BufferedReader(new
                        InputStreamReader(
                        conn.getInputStream()));

                StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("Success");
                String line="";
                getMethod();

                while((line = in.readLine()) != null) {

                    sb.append(line);
                    break;
                }

                in.close();
                return sb.toString();


            }
            else {
                return new String("false : "+responseCode);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            return new String("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

public String getPostDataString(JSONObject params) throws Exception {

    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    boolean first = true;

    Iterator<String> itr = params.keys();

    while(itr.hasNext()){

        String key= itr.next();
        Object value = params.get(key);

        if (first)
            first = false;
        else
            result.append("&");

        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(key, "UTF-8"));
        result.append("=");
        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(value.toString(), "UTF-8"));

    }
    return result.toString();
}
```

Do somebody have an idea to solve it?

Thank you for your time.

**EDIT:**

Thanks to @user6749691, now I have got the following script to do the GET method:

```
private void openConnection(String method, URL url) {
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setReadTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
        conn.setRequestMethod(method);
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);

        OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
        writer.write(getPostDataString(postDataParams));
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
        os.close();
}

public URL getMethod() throws IOException {

    return new URL("https://www.webpage.com/login_app.php?username=" + precio );
}
```

And then I call the function `openConnection("GET", getMethod());` in the following lines of the 'SendPostRequest' class:

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("Success");
String line="";
openConnection("GET", getMethod());
while((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
.
.
.
```

But I am getting Unhandled Exception in 'url.openConnection()' and in 'conn.setRequestMethod(method);'

Answer (score 1):

First of all, try to use some great networking library as [Retrofit](https://github.com/square/retrofit) or [Volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html?hl=pt-br).

Inside your getMethod you are just creating URL object. You need to open new URL connection.

Something like this:

```
 private void openConnection(String method, URL url) {
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setReadTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
        conn.setRequestMethod(method);
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);

        OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
        writer.write(getPostDataString(postDataParams));
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
        os.close();
}
```

and then :

```
public URL getMethod() throws IOException {

    return new URL("https://www.webpage.com/login_app.php?username=" + precio );
}

openConnection("GET", getMethod());
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Cannot resolve symbol 'Url'

Comment: I edited my post, but be aware, this is not recommended! This may cause you a lot of trouble if you don't know what you are doing so try to include retrofit or volley in your app and use it

Comment: Thank you for your advises. It is an app just for testing and learning. I will include retrofit. Cannot resolve symbol postDataParams too

Comment: Just try to look into code and you can see that this code is just an example...if you're not goint to make POST requst, just GET you can remove whole Outputstream code because you don't need it...

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
private String openConnection(String requestMethod, String link) {
    URL url;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("");
    try {
        BufferedReader reader;
        if(requestMethod == "GET"){
            url = new URL(link);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod(requestMethod);
            conn.setUseCaches(false);
            conn.setDoInput(true);

            conn.connect();

            int STATUS = conn.getResponseCode();
            Log.e(TAG, "ResponseCode: " + STATUS);

            if(STATUS == 200 || STATUS == 201)
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            else
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getErrorStream()));

            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "");
            }
        }
        else {
            url = new URL(link);
            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            jsonSend.put("your_parameter", "parameter_value");

            String output = jsonSend.toString();
            OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(
                    conn.getOutputStream());
            wr.write(output);
            wr.flush();

            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    conn.getInputStream()));
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "");
            }
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

---

For the best practice, try to use the [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/)